# Negation of the conjunction

Tags: logic

I began to study mathematical logic. Can you show how to prove this exercise

$$ \lnot (A \land B) \Leftrightarrow \lnot A \lor \lnot B $$

in a formal language?

Comment: Easy with truth table; if not allowed, please specify the formal system you are using : Natural Deduction, Truth Trees, etc.

Comment: What is the exercise? All that has been posted is a formula.   Please also use TeX formatting, rather than images, when you post questions.

Comment: The formula $$\lnot (A \land B) \Leftrightarrow \lnot A \land \lnot B$$ isn't valid. Did you mean $$\lnot (A \land B) \Leftrightarrow \lnot A \lor \lnot B$$ maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Consider all the cases (*i.e.* build a truth table).

If $A$ is true and $B$ is true... what happen ?

If $A$ is true and $B$ is false... what happen ?

And so on...

Comment: Is it a formal proof?

Comment: @J.Doe Absolutely, considering all the cases is a formal proof.

Comment: @J.Doe: There are many kinds of formal proof. If you want to produce a particular kind of formal proof, you need to disclose _which_ kind that is.